# Using willChangeValueForKey/didChangeValueForKey with OSSpinLockLock

Tags: objective-c, ios5, grand-central-dispatch

I want to issue a notification when all 4 different threads have finished their work. I'm keeping count of the total threads and have a listener that does some work when the threads have finished.

Is the following a safe way to do this?

```
// ivars:
NSMutableArray *list;
OSSpinLock lock;

#define MAX_ALLOWED 4

- (void)someThreadedWork
{
    // Iterate thru 4 different items using gcd and update
    for (int x = 0; x < MAX_ALLOWED; ++x)
    {
        dispatch_async(some_queue, ^{
           // Do some work.. once done, 
           [self updateCount:ix];
        });
    }
}

- (void)updateCount:(NSInteger)newCount
    OSSpinLockLock(&lock);
    {
        [list addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newCount]];

        if ([list count] == MAX_ALLOWED)
        {
            _allValuesUpdatedAt = [NSDate date];
        }
    }
    OSSpinLockUnlock(&lock);
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object 
change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context 
{
    // When I get the 'allItemsUpdatedAt' event, I will perform some other work
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // there is a corresponding removeObserver in the dealloc
        list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [anInstance addObserver:self 
                forKeyPath:@"allItemsUpdatedAt" 
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HachiEthan's comment about dispatch_async is exactly correct. If you use dispatch_group_async instead, then you don't need any locking at all, nor do you have to keep track of the threads that are currently working. It'll do all of this for you.

See ["Waiting on Groups of Queued Tasks"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) in the Concurrency Programming Guide for a faster, simpler, more robust, and less energy intensive approach to this problem. See also "Migrating Away from Threads" in the same document to learn how to convert thread-based systems to queue-based systems.

Comment: Another option, if the sole goal is simply to do 4 operations in parallel and then do some action when they're finished, is to use dispatch_apply() just like a concurrent for loop, which will also block until they are all done.  I agree that groups are by far the more elegant approach (particularly if you use the async completion callback option) since you can extend that code to handle any number of concurrent block operations as part of the same computational group, but if the task is simple, so is dispatch_apply()!

Comment: I really like the dispatch_group_async option - that feels like it's the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a few things:

**Red Flag:** You change the value of `_allValuesUpdatedAt` inside the lock, but are potentially "reading" its value elsewhere... (e.g. whomever is observing the property `allValuesUpdatedAt`) so unless your `allValuesUpdatedAt` property is also protected by that same `&lock` instance, you've got a problem there.  (Edit: also, your above code is not retaining the NSDate, so it will be autoreleased on you at some point.)

If you use `dispatch_async` and pass it a *serial queue* then you don't need that spin-lock for updating the values in your `list`, provided that the `updateCount:` method is only accessed by code running from that serial queue. (**Note**: You'd still need to protect access to `allValuesUpdatedAt`)

If `updateCount:` does need to be accessed from other code, say, the main thread, then yes you will need some sort of lock there, like you have.

---

EDIT: keeping most of what you have, but addressing the red-flag

```
//header:
@property (atomic, retain) NSDate *allValuesUpdatedAt;

//impl:
- (void)updateCount:(NSInteger)newCount
    OSSpinLockLock(&lock);
    {
        [list addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newCount]];

        if ([list count] == MAX_ALLOWED)
        {
            //use atomic property for read/write thread-safety:
            self.allValuesUpdatedAt = [NSDate date]; 
        }
    }
    OSSpinLockUnlock(&lock);
}
```

Comment: thanks - I didn't note originally but 'allValuesUpdatedAt' is an ivar.